# Find inverse function of exponential function $y=e^x - 2e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How can I find the inverse of

$$y=e^x - 2e^{-x}$$

I normally express the function in terms of $x$. But here, $x$ is in the exponent. If I take $\log$ both sides,

$\lg{y} = \lg{(e^x - 2e^{-x})}$

Which doesn't appear to help, I still can't get the $x$ out?

The question asks to find $(f^{-1})'(1)$

Comment: You really only need to figure out where the inverse is equal to 1 which is a slightly easier problem than figuring out the entire inverse.  In this case that reduces to $1 + 2e^{-x} = e^x$.  taking logs gives that $x = ln(1+2e^{-x})$. Rewriting this as $z=ln(x)$ we get $ln(z) = ln(1+\frac{2}{z})$ and in this form it is easy to see that $z=2$ is the solution.

Edit: I should add that differentiating y it is easy to see that y is 1-1 so the solution is unique.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Chris and Isaac noted, you don't actually need to invert the function. But in case you want to do that anyway, the way to do it is to view
$$ y = e^x - 2e^{-x} $$
as a quadratic equation in $e^x$ -- namely multiply everything by $e^x$ to get
$$ y e^x = (e^x)^2 - 2$$
Now use the quadratic formula to find $e^x$, and *then* take the logarithm of the result.

Answer (score 7):

Since you only need the derivative of the inverse function at a single point, you don't need to find a formula for the inverse function.  The graph of a function and the graph of its inverse are reflection images of one another over $y=x$, which is equivalent to exchanging $x$ and $y$, so the slope of the tangent lines at corresponding points (and hence the derivative at corresponding points) are reciprocals.  If $y=f(x)$, $$(f^{-1})'(y)=\frac{1}{f'(x)}.$$